# Unable to create wireshark installer for windows 7 x32/x64

Tags: windows, wireshark, nsis, windows-7-x64, wireshark-dissector

Trying to create wireshark x64,x32 installers on windows 7 along with my  protocol dissector  facing below issue.

could anybody faced similar issue if so please share some inputs to resolve below issue.

Steps followed:
1)rem Let CMake determine the library download directory name under

2)rem WIRESHARK_BASE_DIR or set it explicitly by using WIRESHARK_LIB_DIR.

3)rem Set *one* of these.

4)set WIRESHARK_BASE_DIR=D:\Development

5)rem set WIRESHARK_LIB_DIR=D:\Development\wireshark-win64-libs

6)rem Set the Qt installation directory

7)set QT5_BASE_DIR=C:\Qt\5.12.5\msvc2017_64

8)rem Append a custom string to the package version. Optional.

9)set WIRESHARK_VERSION_EXTRA=-YourExtraVersionInfo

10)cd D:\Development\wsbuild32

11)cmake -DENABLE_CHM_GUIDES=on -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" -A x64 ..\wireshark

12)msbuild /m /p:Configuration=RelWithDebInfo Wireshark.sln

13)msbuild /m /p:Configuration=RelWithDebInfo nsis_package_prep.vcxproj--->at 
this step throwing error.

**Log:**

!insertmacro: end of FUNCTION_STRING_StrRep
!insertmacro: end of FUNCTION_STRING_UnStrRep
SetCompress: off
OutFile: "D:\Development\wsbuild32\run\RelWithDebInfo\uninstall_instal          ler.exe"
InstType: (uninstall) 1="Default (keep Personal Settings and Npcap)"          InstType: (uninstall) 2="All (remove all)"
UninstallIcon: "....\image\wiresharkinst.ico"
!include: "C:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS\Include\MUI.nsh" (ACP)
!include: "C:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS\Contrib\Modern UI\System.nsh" (          ACP) NSIS Modern User Interface version 1.81 - Copyright 2002-2018 Joost Ve          rburg (C:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS\Contrib\Modern UI\System.nsh:13)          !include: closed: "C:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS\Contrib\Modern UI\Syste          m.nsh"
!include: closed: "C:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS\Include\MUI.nsh"          !define: "MUI_UNICON"="....\image\wiresharkinst.ico"
!define: "MUI_UNCONFIRMPAGE_TEXT_TOP"="The following Wireshark install          ation will be removed. Click 'Next' to continue."
!define: "MUI_UNFINISHPAGE_NOAUTOCLOSE"=""
!insertmacro: MUI_UNPAGE_WELCOME
Plugin directories:
C:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS\Plugins\x86-ansi
Plugin not found, cannot call InstallOptions::initDialog
Error in macro INSTALLOPTIONS_INITDIALOG on macroline 2
Error in macro MUI_FUNCTION_WELCOMEPAGE on macroline 48
Error in macro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME on macroline 23
Error in macro MUI_UNPAGE_WELCOME on macroline 7
Error in script "uninstall.nsi" on line 35 -- aborting creation process
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7        \IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(209,5): error MSB6006: "cm        d.exe" exited with code 1. 
[D:\Development\wsbuild32\nsis_package_prep.v    cxproj] 1>Done Building Project "D:\Development\wsbuild32\nsis_package_prep.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as this [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Your code example has mad problems with formatting. Can you please use [code fences](https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#fenced-code-blocks) in your question?

Comment: Also, please make sure newlines render as such in this formatted code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is

> Plugin not found, cannot call InstallOptions::initDialog

The MakeNSIS compiler cannot find `InstallOptions.dll` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS\Plugins\x86-ansi` but that file should be installed by default.

Try re-installing NSIS.